# Are all group automorphisms of the form $A(x) = g_1xg_2x\cdots x g_n$ conjugations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

I am trying to show that all group automorphisms of the form $A(x) = g_1xg_2x\cdots x g_n$ for fixed elements $g_1, g_2, \cdots g_n \in G$ are conjugations. It is clear that by setting $x$ to the identity we can conclude that $g_1g_2\cdots g_n$ is the identity. However, I have no idea how to show $n=2$. Any hint will be appreciated.

Edit: As pointed out in the comment, this is not true in Abelian groups. However, I'm trying to show this for a larger proof where G is assumed to be non-Abelian.

Comment: Let the $g_i$s all be the identity. Then, $A(x)=x^{n-1}$ is an automorphism if $G$ is a finite abelian group and $n-1$ is coprime to the order of $G$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Thanks! What about non-Abelian cases though? I'm showing this as part of a larger proof where the group G is assumed to be Abelian

Comment: @HangingPawns if it is not true for abelian then it is not true for non-abelian as well. Simply by considering a direct product of previous example with any non-abelian group.

Comment: What makes you think such map are homomorphisms at all?

Comment: Homomorphism property is part of the assumption. @Arturo

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can show that for $n=3$, the map is an automorphism if and only if the group is abelian of odd order. Note that in any case, this is a pointwise product of conjugation morphisms, since you can rewrite as $$(g_1xg_1^{-1})(g_1g_2 x g_2^{-1}g_1^{-1})(g_1g_2g_3 x \cdots )(g_1g_2\cdots g_{n-1}xg_n)$$and as you note, $g_n=(g_1\cdots g_{n-1})^{-1}$ will hold if this is a morphism.

Comment: On the other hand, for the nonabelian group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$, you can take $n=p+2$, all $g_i$ central subject to their product being the identity, and then your map is $A(x) =x^{p+1} = x$, hence an automorphism (the identity, even).

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Or any group of exponent $n-2$, abelian or not.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your maps are actually "pointwise products" of conjugation maps: if this map is a homomorphism, then as you note we obtain that $g_1\cdots g_n=e$ (by plugging in $x=e$), and therefore $g_n=(g_1\cdots g_{n-1})^{-1}$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
g_1xg_2x\cdots xg_n &= (g_1)x(g_1^{-1})(g_1g_2)x(g_1g_2)^{-1}(g_1g_2g_3)x \cdots (g_1\cdots g_{n-1})xg_n\\
&=(g_1xg_1^{-1})(g_1g_2)x(g_1g_2)^{-1}(g_1g_2g_3)x \cdots (g_1\cdots g_{n-1})x(g_1\cdots g_{n-1})^{-1}\\
&= \varphi_{g_1}(x) \varphi_{g_1g_2}(x)\cdots \varphi_{g_1\cdots g_{n-1}}(x),
\end{align*}$$
where $\varphi_g$ is the inner automorphism determined by $g$, $\varphi_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$.

For $n=3$ (that is, the pointwise product of two automorphisms), we get that this must be an abelian group:

**Theorem.** Let $G$ be a group, and let $\varphi,\psi\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$. If $x\longmapsto \varphi(x)\psi(x)$ is an automorphism of $G$, then $G$ is abelian.

*Proof.* Let $x,y\in G$. Since the map is a homomorphism, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
\varphi(xy)\psi(xy) &= \varphi(x)\psi(x)\varphi(y)\psi(y)\\
\varphi(x)\varphi(y)\psi(x)\psi(y) &= \varphi(x)\psi(x)\varphi(y)\psi(y)\\
\varphi(y)\psi(x) &= \psi(x)\varphi(y).
\end{align*}$$
Fix $x$; as $y$ ranges over all elements of $G$, we get that $\psi(x)$ commutes with all elements of $G$ (since $\varphi$ is surjective. Thus, $\psi(x)\in Z(G)$. Since the center is characteristic, it follows that $x\in Z(G)$. Thus, all elements of $G$ are central, so $G$ is abelian. $\Box$

**Corollary.** If $A(x) = g_1xg_2xg_3$ is an automorphism, then $G$ is an abelian group with no elements of order $2$ and $A(x)=x^2$. If $G$ is finite, then $G$ is of odd order.

*Proof.* We have that $A(x) = \varphi_{g_1}(x)\varphi_{g_1g_2}(x)$, so by the THeorem $G$ is abelian, and in particular $\varphi_{y}(x)=x$ for all $y\in G$. Thus, $A(x)=x^2$. As this is an automorphism, $x^2=e$ implies $x=e$. $\Box$

In particular, if $G$ is non-abelian, then $n=3$ is impossible.

However, larger values of $n$ are possible. Specifically, if $G$ has exponent $k$, then you can take $n=k+1$ and $g_1=\cdots g_n=e$. Then $A(x) = x^{n} = x^{k+1}=x$ for all $x\in G$, so $A$ is of course an automorphism. Note that there are nonabelian groups of exponent $n$ for every $n\neq 1,2$.

I'm not sure what happens if we require that the $g_i$ be non-central; you still have a pointwise product of $n-1$ (nontrivial inner) automorphisms. Using the same trick as for $n=3$, we can conclude that we have endomorphisms $\psi_1,\ldots,\psi_k$, and for all $x,y\in G$ we have
$$\begin{align*}
\psi_1(x)\psi_1(y)\cdots \psi_k(x)\psi_k(y)&= \psi_1(x)\cdots\psi_k(x)\psi_1(y)\cdots\psi_k(y)\\
\psi_1(y)\psi_2(x)\psi_2(y)\cdots\psi_{k-1}(y)\psi_k(x) &= \psi_2(x)\cdots \psi_k(x)\psi_1(y)\cdots\psi_{k-1}(y),
\end{align*}$$
but I don't see how one might exploit that.